# How do I generate loadable modules during Linux kernel build?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I seem to successfully build a kernel image, but I can not generate all the modules I expect. I expect more modules since I see them enabled in the gconfig window. [Here](http://pastebin.com/g0dywpQc) is a copy of my make session. Seems like make goes into the devices directories. I can not figure out why it is not create the .ko files. I expect to see .ko files. I have checked the Makefile in /drivers directory, and I can see that it is configured with a number of lines like

```
obj-$(CONFIG_PCI)               += pci/
```

Which directs make to build the pci module for instance. I think this implies that I should see a number .ko files. But I do not. I have seen just one .ko file for scsi module. I like to be able to build all of modules selected.

I also verified that a number of mudules are enabled when I issued:

```
make VARIANT_DEFCONFIG=msm8974_sec_hlte_spr_defconfig msm8974_sec_defconfig SELINUX_DEFCONFIG=selinux_defconfig gconfig
```

But as I said, I do not see any of them. What am I missing please?

@Subin - Thanks. I just tried make modules_install. I have to mention that I am cross compiling this for an arm target. I believe modules_install is for the purpose of installing the driver for the machine you are on? I got a message about needing to be in root, and I did not proceed. I have been wondering when I need to run it. What does it do exactly please?

Re: the make modules; I have run it before. I'll run it again and post the result. Since I got one .ko file I figured the issue is something different between that one module, and every other one enabled in my config. Here is what I got when I ran make modules:

```
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ make modules
CHK     include/linux/version.h
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
```

Re: your comment on the location of .ko files, I am doing a find to see if perhaps I am not looking at the right place, it only finds the one which was built. Not the other ones. Here is the output:

```
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ find . -type f -name "*.ko"
./drivers/scsi/scsi_wait_scan.ko
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$
```

Should I perhaps run make v=1, in verbose mode that is? Would that provide more information on why the other modules are not built?

@Gil Hamilton - Thanks. You are right. Here is an excerpt of the .config file:

```
#
# SCSI support type (disk, tape, CD-ROM)
#
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD=y
# CONFIG_CHR_DEV_ST is not set
# CONFIG_CHR_DEV_OSST is not set
# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR is not set
CONFIG_CHR_DEV_SG=y
CONFIG_CHR_DEV_SCH=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MULTI_LUN=y
CONFIG_SCSI_CONSTANTS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_LOGGING=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SCAN_ASYNC=y
CONFIG_SCSI_WAIT_SCAN=m
```

This entry is the only one set to 'm'.

Comment: Have you run "make modules" and/or "make modules_install" ? If you want the modules in a specific directory, do "export INSTALL_MOD_PATH=<path>" before make modules_install. Else look in /lib/modules/<kernel version>/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most device driver modules in the linux kernel build system use a tristate (3-valued) configuration setting. The options are

- 'n' (don't build at all),
- 'y' (build and link statically into the main kernel object), and
- 'm' (build as module for dynamic loading).

The values are determined by the content of .config. The values in .config are usually generated from an existing config file (look in arch/`<ARCH>`/configs for your `<ARCH>`). Also check the output of 'make help' for interesting configuration targets.

If you're not seeing the `.ko` files being created, that indicates the corresponding configuration variable is either set to 'y' or 'n'.